# Mac Automator using FFMPEG to generate thumbnails with shell script

Tags: bash, mac, automator

I've added the following to the Run Shell Script Object

```
for f in "$@"
do
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -ss 3 -i "$f" -v quiet -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)" -vframes 1 "$f.png"
done
```

the ffmpeg line works fine directly in the bash shell but when I run the workflow, nothing happens (no errors either). The vframes switch is just so I can tune the number of thumbs I want.

Any help?

Comment: I found the issue. I had automator set to stdin instead of 'as arguments', so it wasn't passing the finder objects as args. Ended up using this to get a movie poster sized thumbnail (scaling up, preserving aspect and cropping to 1/1.5)

    for f in "$@"
    do
        /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -ss 20 -i "$f" -v error -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I),scale=-1:640,crop=ih*.5:640" -qscale:v 3 -vframes 1 "$f.jpg
    done

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had automator set to stdin instead of 'as arguments', so it wasn't passing the finder objects as args. Ended up using this to get a movie poster sized thumbnail (scaling up, preserving aspect and cropping to 1/1.5)

```
for f in "$@"
do 
   /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -ss 20 -i "$f" -v error -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I),scale=-1:640,crop=ih*.5:640" -qscale:v 3 -vframes 1 "$f.jpg 
done
```